# Any reason why this unit test for DateFormatter in swift is failing when we run the pipeline but works on local?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, pipeline

So the following unit test is working good in our local, but when we run the pipeline the test failed. Any reason why is this happening?

**Function to test**

```
public extension DateFormatter {
    func fromYesterday(date: String?, today: String?) -> Bool {
        guard let dateString = date,
              let todayString = today,
              let date = self.date(from: dateString),
              let today = self.date(from: todayString) else {
            return false
        }

        guard let dayBefore = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: today) else {
            return false
        }

        return self.calendar.isDate(date, inSameDayAs: dayBefore)
    }
}
```

**Test files**

```
struct DateFormatterStubs {
    static var defaultDateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: -5)
        return formatter
    }()
}

class DateFormatterExtensionTests: XCTestCase {

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatterStubs.defaultDateFormatter

    func testFromYesterday_todayAsDayBeforeDayThanGivenDate_returnsTrue() {
        var date: String = "2021-01-09T23:59:59-05:00"
        var today: String = "2021-01-10T00:00:00-05:00"

        XCTAssertTrue(dateFormatter.fromYesterday(date: date, today: today))

        date = "2021-01-09T00:00:00-05:00"
        today = "2021-01-10T23:59:59-05:00"

        XCTAssertTrue(dateFormatter.fromYesterday(date: date, today: today))
    }
}
```

I expect the unit test have some mock data to pass the pipeline run.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with pipeline but I am guessing some kind of CI running on a server? One possible issue is that the timezone for the formatter is set to 5 seconds from GMT.

Comment: Yes, when I said pipeline is the CI running on a server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you are using the date formatter's `calendar` to determine if the two dates are in the same day.

```
self.calendar.isDate(date, inSameDayAs: dayBefore)
```

However, you never set `dateFormatter.calendar` in your tests, so the current system calendar is used. This means that `formatter.calendar.timeZone` is the system's time zone.

While `2021-01-09T23:59:59-05:00` is in the previous day of `2021-01-10T00:00:00-05:00` at UTC-5, that isn't necessarily true for other timezones. Your local system might be using a timezone with a -5 offset at that time, but the pipeline server uses a different timezone.

For the tests to succeed, you can set `formatter.calendar.timeZone` to -5 hours:

```
dateFormatter.calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: -5 * 60 * 60)!
```

Note that setting `formatter.timeZone` is unnecessary, since there is already an offset in your date-time string.